# How to know the source repository of a package in debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, source, version-control

In Debian, AFAIK some packages are maintained in Subversion (famously team-pkg-gnome), while some are maintained in git, and others in some other VCS.

Is there a way to know where the source of a package is without doing an `apt-get source $PACKAGENAME`?

I tried three methods and all failed :-

```
$apt show $PACKAGENAME
$aptitude show $PACKAGENAME 
$apt-cache show $PACKAGENAME
```

none of the above are able to give/share this information.

Is there anyway to get the information. I need to know the source repo. name and whether it is in git, svn or some other version control.

Comment: apt-cache policy <package>.  Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/106794/how-to-tell-from-what-ubuntu-or-debian-repository-a-package-comes

Comment: @h3rrmiller that's showing you where the package is downloaded from, not where the source for the package is hosted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Using CLI tools

As indicated by [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert), Debian packages which are maintained in a VCS are supposed to indicate this in a pair of `Vcs-...` fields in their source package.

The best tool to use this information is `debcheckout` in the `devscripts` package, or `apt-cache showsrc`. Both of these will show you `gnome-disk-utility`'s repository information.

```
apt-cache showsrc gnome-disk-utility
```

will show all the information contained in the source package, including links to the VCS (`Vcs-Brower` gives a link for use in a brower, `Vcs-Git` give the link to clone the git repository, assuming the repository uses git):

```
Vcs-Browser: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-disk-utility
Vcs-Git: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-disk-utility.git
```

whereas

```
debcheckout -d gnome-disk-utility
```

will only show the VCS information and pertinent details (if the package is hosted in a VCS).

### Checkout

If you then want to check the source out,

```
debcheckout gnome-disk-utility
```

will do that for you.

## Web Interface

You can also see this information on the [Debian Package Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/), which will link to the VCS where the package is hosted (if there is one).

Answer (score 14):

A lot of package include this in their control information in the `Vcs-*` fields. You can see it easily (and without downloading the source package) using `apt-cache showsrc`.

```
$ apt-cache showsrc gnome-disk-utility
⋮
Vcs-Browser: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-disk-utility
Vcs-Git: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-disk-utility.git
⋮
```

So in this case, you could do a `git clone https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-disk-utility.git` to download the source, or browse it on the web at https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-disk-utility.

Not all packages have `Vcs-*` fields. They can be missing because the maintainer doesn't use a VCS (or at least not a public one), or hasn't added the headers for some other reason. `apt-get source packagename` will always get the source, though not via a VCS. Similarly, you can browse all the source online at http://sources.debian.net/

(Note: you will need `deb-src` lines in your `sources.list` file.)

**Update:** [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) points out `debcheckout -d`; first time I'd heard of it too. See (and upvote) [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224519/977) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You are not entirely right: the Debian source code is in source packages: you need some lines with `deb-src` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` like e.g.

```
 deb-src http://ftp2.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

<sup>(adapt that to your geography and habits)</sup>

Then you can ask that source code to be built from source using e.g. `aptitude build` (and you might want to use `aptitude build-dep` to install the packages needed for that build).

The Debian maintainers are packaging the source code by incorporating their patches relative to some upstream software repository. That upstream software repository uses (or perhaps not) the version control system they want to use.