# Where is the source repo for Debian utilities?

Tags: debian, repository

Where can I find the official repository for the source code for `postgresql-contrib`'s `pg_updatedicts`.

The top of the file shows

```
(C) 2012-2016 Christoph Berg <myon@debian.org>
```

So I know I could always email him, but isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/postgresql-common), and look for the VCS links. You can [browse the git repository here](https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common). [`pg_updatedicts` is here](https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common/blob/master/pg_updatedicts).

On a correctly-configured Debian system,

```
apt-get source postgresql-contrib
```

will download and extract the source code. You can also install `debcheckout` and use that instead to clone the VCS repository.

You can see the VCS links from a Debian system using `apt-cache showsrc`, for example `apt-cache showsrc postgresql-contrib`, or [`debcheckout -d`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224519/86440).