# How to make apt read a different sources.list

Tags: apt, sudo, make, source, configure

I am trying to install a program for my user because I don't have sudo privileges.

I tried to install `dos2unix` package as follows:

```
apt-get source dos2unix 
./configure --prefix=$HOME/myapps
make
make install
```

But I get the following error:

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

As I cannot edit sources.list, is there a way to make apt-get read another file?

Comment: Don't think you can, the only way to get `apt` to use a different `source` is to add a repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, but for that you need to create a file in that folder and only root can do that.

Comment: @Hunter there is a way, see my answer ;-).

Comment: It might be easier to `apt-get download dos2unix; dpkg-deb -x dos2unix*.deb`, but dependencies will be a problem either way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* use another `sources.list`, and as [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) pointed out, it’s as simple as

```
apt -o "Dir::Etc::sourcelist=/path/to/your/sources.list" source dos2unix
```

The documentation suggests that this isn’t possible except in a configuration file, but it turns out the documentation is wrong (see the revision history for the configuration file variant).

Alternatively, you could clone the package source directly, if the package is maintained in a revision control system. `apt showsrc dos2unix` shows

```
Vcs-Git: https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/dos2unix.git
```

so if you have `git` installed you can clone that. `debcheckout`, in the `devscripts` package, can automate that for you, but you probably don’t have that installed... See [How to know the source repository of a package in debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224500/86440) for details.

Comment: I learn something new here everyday!

Comment: Can't apt configuration options also be passed as command line options? A la https://askubuntu.com/a/698028/158442

Comment: Indeed @muru, I was trusting the documentation which says that the `Dir::Etc` options can’t be set on the command-line!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See Stephen Kitt's excellent answer. I'm not deleting this answer because although you asked 'How to make apt read a different sources.list", you seem to really just want to get a single source tarball for a one-time purpose, and for that its simplest to just perform a manual download.

PRIOR ANSWER
`apt-get` is primarily a program for privileged users for system-wide maintenance. You want a solution for a non-privileged user to perform a local task.

There are several ways to manually get the sources:

1) Directly from the debian website by performing a web search for "debian package dos2unix". The link to the source tarball is on the right side of the page.

2) Directly from the developer. Run `apt-cache show [package-name]` and find the url for the developer homepage. In this particular case, this won't be helpful because the link is bad.