# Where to find the source of the kernel package on a debian armhf BeagleBone Black build?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, beagleboneblack

On [a BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images) the [Linux release installed is a bone-debian-9.2-iot-armhf-2017-10-10-4gb.img](http://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-9.2-iot-armhf-2017-10-10-4gb.img.xz). After booting the stock system, it is updated to the `Linux 4.9.37-ti-r47` image by:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-4.9.37-ti-r47
apt-get install linux-firmware-image-4.9.37-ti-r47
```

Everything works fine. Now I uncommented all the `deb-src` line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Did a `apt-get update`. And followed the steps in [the related SO: how to know the source repository of a package in debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224500/how-to-know-the-source-repository-of-a-package-in-debian), to find out where to get the source code. Unfortunately it turns up an error:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/debian# apt-cache showsrc linux-image-4.9.37-ti-r47
W: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.9.37-ti-r47
N: No packages found
```

Where to find the source package that can be used to build the binary kernel?

I did the same for the `bash` package. It works fine.

Comment: Did you just want the kernel source?  https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/releases/tag/4.9.37-ti-r47

Comment: @tk421 It's interesting that the source does not reside with the released binaries. I'm looking for building the exactly same linux-image-<version> package as installed to the target. If you know how to create the deb, please convert your comment and further information into an answer. That will be great. Thanks!

Comment: I looked but no such luck.

Comment: I figured the code might not exist as a snapshot. There is a build script which will fetch the code and patch from multiple repos. I'll post an answer if it does show functionally as good as the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the source code does not exist in a single package/snapshot.

There is a build script from https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black . The script is pulling code in three steps:

- It clones from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
- Then it fetches from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
- Finally it pulls from https://github.com/RobertCNelson/ti-linux-kernel.git  and applies the patches from this repo.

When all these steps are done, the build script tags and commits the code.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, otherwise other might look if know a better answer.